# Click events on Array of buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

How can I get the name of the object last clicked on a panel? The trick is there is a big array of buttons on the panel (btn[1] ... btn [200]). How can I check if I clicked on button b[180], or b[11] or even outside the panel (no button)? Also the buttons are generated at page load via coding.
Thank you. Anna

EDIT: 
Thank you! Another issue that arose (this generated a NULL object reference):
I have a method on the same level as buttonHandler(), it is named HowManyClicked() and it's called from within buttonHandler(). Inside HowManyClicked() I want to identify Button btn1 = Panel2.FindControl(x) as Button; where x is, for example, buttonArray[2,3]. But I always get NULL. **Is the button array buttonArray not identifiable by name once out of the method that generated it**??

```
        public void buttonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            //string tt = btn.ToolTip.ToString();
            btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
            statusL.Text = HowManyClicked().ToString();

        }

        public int HowManyClicked()
        {
            int sum=0;
            for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
                for (int b = 0; b < 14; b++)
                {
                    string x = "buttonArray[" + a + ", " + b + "]";
                    statusL.Text = x;
                    Button btn1 = Panel2.FindControl(x) as Button;
                    if (btn1.BackColor == Color.Red) sum += 1;

                }
            return sum;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @AVD commented you can get the button originating the postback casting the sender object, you can also use the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties from the button object (they are usually used when the button is inside a `Grid`, `DataList` etc but you can use them in this context if you need):

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            var b = new Button();
            b.Text = "My Button " + item.ToString();
            b.CommandName = "custom command";
            b.CommandArgument = item.ToString();
            b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
            this.myPanel.Controls.Add(b);
        }
    }

    void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var current = sender as Button;
        this.lblMessage2.Text = "Clicked from array buttons: <br/>Command Name: " + current.CommandName + "<br/>Args: " + current.CommandArgument + "<br/>Button Unique ID: " + current.UniqueID + "<br/>Client ID: " + current.ClientID;
    }
```

Page:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPanel">
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Label ID="lblMessage2" runat="server" />
```

This code generates something like:

[image]

As an additional note, Microsoft recommends to create dynamic controls in the `PreInit` event or in case you are using a master page, in the `Init` event

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

## Edited

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.ViewState["count"] = 0;
        }

    }


    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            var b = new Button();
            b.Text = "My Button " + item.ToString();
            b.Click += new EventHandler(buttonHandler);
            this.myPanel.Controls.Add(b);
        }
    }

    void buttonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // update here your control
        var b = sender as Button;
        b.BackColor = Color.Red;
        HowManyClicked();
    }

    private void HowManyClicked()
    {
        var c = (int)this.ViewState["count"];
        c++;
        this.ViewState["count"] = c;
        this.lblMessage2.Text = "Clicked controls: " + this.ViewState["count"].ToString();
    }
```

This produced:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, Jupanol. Anoter thing: I have a method on the same level as buttonHandler(), it is named HowManyClicked() and it's called from within buttonHandler(). Inside HowManyClicked() I want to identify Button btn1 = Panel2.FindControl(x) as Button; where x is, for example, buttonArray[2,3]. But I always get NULL. Is the button array buttonArray not identifiable by name once out of the method that generated it: PopulateControls??

Comment: Why don't you just pass as a parameter to `HowManyClicked` the button from `buttonHandler` like this `HowManyClicked(Button button)` and `buttonHandler{HowManyClicked(sender as Button)}`

Comment: Well, HowManyClicked() is meant to calculate/update after each click, how many buttons were clicked in total/overall. So that's why I didn't use parameters for the method signature. It's more of a general inquiry, doesn't refer to a button.

Comment: Great, many thanks Jupanol! I just figured another way to do this: public int HowManyClicked() { int sum=0; foreach (Control cnt in this.Panel2.Controls) if (cnt is Button) { Button btn = (Button)cnt;
if (btn.BackColor == Color.Red) sum += 1;} return sum; }
            
        }

Comment: This works too, by just redefining HowManyClicked() but still not sure what the exaplanation is of why my first method didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the name of the object last clicked on a panel?

The first parameter of click handler returns the reference of control/object has raised the event.

```
public void buttonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn=sender as Button;
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out another fix by just redefining HowManyClicked() so I am adding it here below. Not sure still why the first method (the one in my question) didn't work also. Here goes:

```
public int HowManyClicked()
        {
            int sum=0;
            foreach (Control cnt in this.Panel2.Controls)
                if (cnt is Button)
                {
                    Button btn = (Button)cnt;
                    if (btn.BackColor == Color.Red)
                        sum += 1;
                }
            return sum;
           }

        }
```

Thanks everyone!