# Dynamically Added DropDownlists Are Not Firing SelectedIndexChanged Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I saw lots of thing about this topic but i can't fin a solution.
I add many dropdown list with one event but they are not firing SelectedIndexChanged evet.
Here is drplist creator code:

```
foreach (var row in cmdSelectCats.ExecuteReader())
{
    var id = row["ProductCategoryID"].ToString();

    var dropDownStatus = new DropDownList {ID = "DrpStatus-" + id};

    dropDownStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Aktif", "1"));
    dropDownStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Pasif", "2"));

    dropDownStatus.AutoPostBack = true; 
    dropDownStatus.SelectedIndexChanged += Status_SelectedIndexChanged;

    var tableCell = new TableCell();
    tableCell.Controls.Add(dropDownStatus);
    dropDownStatus.SelectedValue = row["ProductCategoryStatusID"].ToString();
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
    TblCatList.Rows.Add(tableRow);
}
```

And ofcourse my Event:

```
public void Status_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: did you check the control existence after postback? By `End of the Page life cycle` all controls will be `Disposed`. On each `Postback` `Dynamic Control` needs recreation. The above mentioned code should be in Page `Initialization` event.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a common issue and it's related to the page life cycle:

Take a look at the following questions:

[Click events on Array of buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11061675/1268570)

[Button array disappears after click event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11061754/1268570)

[Dynamically create an ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11061872/1268570)

Now the basic steps to remember when creating dynamic controls are:

- Dynamic controls should be created in the `PreInit` event when you are not working with a master page, if you are, then create the controls in the `Init` event
- Avoid setting properties that can be changed in each post in these events because when the view state is applied (in a post event) the properties will be overridden
- Dynamic controls **must be created every time the page is posted**, avoid this `if(!this.IsPostBack) this.CreatemyDynamicControls();`
- When you create the controls in the `PreInit` or `Init` events, their states will be automatically set in a post event, which means in the `LoadComplete` event your controls will contain their state back even when you create them again in each post and even when you did not explicitly set their state. *Note this behavior is different when you are dealing with controls created at design time, in that case, the event where the state has been set is the Load event*
- Event subscription should occur before the `PageLoadComplete` or they will not be raised

Consider the following description from MSDN

> If controls are created dynamically at run time or declaratively within templates of data-bound controls, their events are initially not synchronized with those of other controls on the page. For example, for a control that is added at run time, the Init and Load events might occur much later in the page life cycle than the same events for controls created declaratively. Therefore, from the time that they are instantiated, dynamically added controls and controls in templates raise their events one after the other until they have caught up to the event during which it was added to the Controls collection.

The above is not so clear to me, but I have found the following. The following `TextBox`'s are created at design time

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtDesignTextBox1.Text = "From PreInit";
        this.txtDesignTextBox1.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtDesignTextBox2.Text = "From Init";
        this.txtDesignTextBox2.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtDesignTextBox3.Text = "From Load";
        this.txtDesignTextBox3.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

At first sight you might think that in every post all the textboxes are updated with the current date, but this is not the case, since they were created at design time they follow strictly the ASP.Net page life-cycle which means, **their state is overriden after the PreInit and Init events**, only the `txtDesignTextBox3` is updated in every post because its `Text` property is updated **after the view state** has been set (in the `Load` event).

But with **dynamic** controls the behavior is different, remember the MSDN description:

> for a control that is added at run time, the Init and Load events might occur much later in the page life cycle

Consider the following:

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox { Text = "From PreInit", Width = new Unit("100%") };
        textBox.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
        this.myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox { Text = "From Init", Width = new Unit("100%") };
        textBox.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
        this.myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox { Text = "From Load", Width = new Unit("100%") };
        textBox.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
        this.myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }
```

In this case, the controls behave slightly different, in this case, in each post, **the controls are never updated** not even the controls created in the `Load` event

The reason is their life-cycle events occurs much later in the page-life cycle which means their state is overridden **even after the Load event**

To solve this, you can use the `LoadComplete` event, in this event you can change the state of dynamic controls:

```
    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox { Text = "From LoadComplete", Width = new Unit("100%") };
        textBox.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
        this.myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }
```

In this case, the state will be updated in each post.

However, take in consideration that you should subscribe to dynamic controls events, before the `LoadComplete` event or they will not be raised.

*... I know I hate this kind of behavior, that's why I love MVC*

As a quick reference for controls created at design time: Notice how the `LoadViewState` method is called **after** the `PreInit` and `Init` events but before the `Load` event. The `Load` event is considered *stable* because in this event you can access the view state of your controls. Also notice that the `RaisePostBackEvent` method represent the control event that caused the post back, this can be, the `SelectedIndexChanged`, `Click`, etc this event is handled *after* the `Load` event

[image]

For a complete detailed specification read [the MSDN Page Life-Cycle documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was an extremely useful piece of information.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot ! My page is working now. I just add the items to the dynamic dropdownlist in Page_LoadComplete() and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

I have usually seen this caused by a page lifecycle problem.  If the control is only created when an event is fired, then when your index changed event fires the control doesn't exist to bind it to on the postback.

Example:

1. MyEvent fires.  Drop-down created.  Event Handler specified.
2. Index Changed event triggered. Page reloads. Drop-down not found, cannot fire.

You have to ensure the drop-down is created before .NET attemps to handle the event.

Answer (score -4):

You are missing:
1- Override SaveViewState
2- Override LoadViewState

I provide a sample code for this question. I test it. It's work.

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">
</div>
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private List<string> values = new List<string>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }        

        protected override object SaveViewState()
        {
            object baseState = base.SaveViewState();            
            object[] allStates = new object[2];
            allStates[0] = baseState;
            allStates[1] = values;
            return allStates;
        }

        protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
        {
            object[] myState = (object[])savedState;
            if (myState[0] != null)
                base.LoadViewState(myState[0]);
            if (myState[1] != null)
            {
                values = (List<string>)myState[1];
                MyRender();
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "ClientID" + i;

                ddl.Items.Add("Item 1");
                ddl.Items.Add("Item 2");
                ddl.AutoPostBack = true;                
                values.Add(ddl.SelectedValue);

                myDiv.Controls.Add(ddl);
            }
        }

        private void MyRender()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            {
                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "ClientID" + i;

                ddl.Items.Add("Item 1");
                ddl.Items.Add("Item 2");
                ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
                ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);

                myDiv.Controls.Add(ddl);
            }
        }

        void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblDescription.Text = ((DropDownList)sender).ID + ": Selected Index Changed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You Should not put whole code...save resources....instesd post a link that whould explain your answer.