# Dynamically loaded dropdownlist control doesn't fire SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net

I have the control `dropdownlist` which has been loaded inside the template column of `RadGrid`.
While loading I have set `AutoPostBack='True'` for `dropdownlist` and also created the event `SelectedIndexChanged`.

```
 DropDownList ddlConditions = new DropDownList(); 
 ddlConditions.ID = "ddl" + name;
 ddlConditions.AutoPostBack = true;
 ddlConditions.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlConditions_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

My question is while i change the selected index of `dropdownlist` the event `SelectedIndexChanged` is not getting triggered.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this caused by a `page life cycle problem`. When your index changed event of Dropdownlist fires the control doesn't exist to bind it on the postback.

Example:

-> MyEvent fires. 
-> Drop-down created. 
-> Event Handler specified.
-> Index Changed event triggered. Page reloads. Drop-down not found, cannot fire.

So you have to `ensure that the drop-down is created before` .NET attempts to handle the event.

Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11127064/1740379) for more information regarding this type of issue and **life cycle**.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to check the place where you have created **DropDownList**. Dynamic controls should be added on **OnInit** or at least on **OnLoad**. After OnLoad finishes executing ASP.NET starts processing control's events and values.

> My question is while i change the selected index of dropdownlist the
>   event SelectedIndexChanged is not getting triggered.

**Answer:** because you have created DropDownList after the events have been processed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page posting back? If so, you'll need to make sure that the control is recreated on the page on every postback.

If it's inside the usual `if(!IsPostBack)` block, then put it outside - Usually, it's prudent to create controls in `page_init` as well, but that can depend on your specific setup.