# I need to dynamically create a control with variable and pass variable to sub

Tags: vb.net, variables, code-behind

I thought this might be easy, but I don't seem to be getting it. I'm working in VB.  I'm dynamically creating rows within a table but I wish to add an "EDIT" link/button/event-trigger-of-some-kind that fires a sub, but I need to pass a variable to the sub. The code is as follows.  Note the variable that I need to pass is an integer.

```
Dim CellDescriptionEdit As New TableCell()
RowNameDescription.Cells.Add(CellDescriptionEdit)
CellDescriptionEdit.ID = "CellDescriptionEdit" & UserReader("fldClaimPmtID")
Dim LinkButtonEdit As New LinkButton
LinkButtonEdit.CommandArgument = UserReader("fldClaimPmtID")
LinkButtonEdit.OnClientClick = "LinkButtonEdit_OnClick"
LinkButtonEdit.Text = "EDIT"
CellDescriptionEdit.Controls.Add(LinkButtonEdit)
```

Then the sub looks like this...

```
Protected Sub LinkButtonEdit_OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   'Lots of happy code but for example purposes let's use this...        
    lblTest.Text = Int32.Parse(btn.CommandArgument)
End Sub
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  Where would I put that?

Comment: In the `lblTest.Text = (here)` line. But @LarsTech, isn't `Int32.Parse(DirectCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument)` the correct approach in VB.NET?

Comment: @VisualVincent Yep, your way.  I was in c# mode.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work.  I've changed it to:
    Protected Sub LinkButtonEdit_OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
         'Lots of happy code but for example purposes let's use this...        
         lblTest.Text = Int32.Parse(DirectCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument)
    End Sub

Comment: What's the problem? Is there an exception?

Comment: It doesn't fire the lblTest.Text.  No exception is thrown.

Comment: Does it change if you set `lblTest.Text` to something else?

Comment: It doesn't change.  Nothing seems to happen.  I'm creating the table in page_load.  Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: No joy.  I'll have a look at that article.

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Comment: And bingo...  Works like a charm.  Thanks bundles!

Comment: Any time. Glad you finally got it working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add eventhandlers to your controls you have use the `AddHandler` statement:

```
AddHandler LinkButtonEdit.OnClientClick, AddressOf LinkButtonEdit_OnClick
```

So replace this:

```
LinkButtonEdit.OnClientClick = "LinkButtonEdit_OnClick"
```

With the code at the top.

---

This is also something to consider looking at if you use ASP.NET: [Dynamically Added DropDownlists Are Not Firing SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126029/dynamically-added-dropdownlists-are-not-firing-selectedindexchanged-event/11127064#11127064)