# SelectIndexChanged doesn´t work in dynamic drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I working with ASP.NET WebForms with C#. I have a button when clicking on it creates a dropdownlist. This list is created in the "createlist" method with parameters such as id and items. I also add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.

The list is created successfully, but when I switch between the 3 options the handler is not firing, because the console never prints the message "CHANGE".

Here's my code:

```
namespace web
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        List<string> lstDivs = new List<string>();

        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control results = FindControl("results");
            lstDivs.Add("One");
            lstDivs.Add("Two");
            lstDivs.Add("Three");
            DropDownList lstTipo = createList("lstTipos", lstDivs);
            results.Controls.Add(lstTipo);
        }        

        public DropDownList createList(string id, List<string> lstStr)
        {
            DropDownList lst = new DropDownList();
            lst.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            lst.ID = id + "" + Variables.numDiv;
            lst.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(change);
            lst.AutoPostBack = true;

            lst.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select...", "Select..."));
            for (int i = 0; i < lstStr.Count; i++)
            {
                lst.Items.Add(new ListItem(lstStr[i], lstStr[i]));
                lst.Items[i].Attributes.Add("id", lst.ID + "" + i.ToString());
            }

            return lst;
        }

        protected void change(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Write("CHANGE\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once a dynamic control is created and displayed to the user, it has to be recreated on a postback for its events to fire. Execution of events is triggered by the control itself, hence, if there is no control - there is nobody to detect the change and call your `change` method.

You have to persist the fact that the dropdown has been created (hidden field, ViewState, Session, database, ...) and create it again in `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your control exists on the postback since it is dynamically created. I found this post which might be helpful:
[Dynamically Added DropDownlists Are Not Firing SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126029/dynamically-added-dropdownlists-are-not-firing-selectedindexchanged-event)

Also, I don't think you need to add the runat as an attribute. This should be done automatically.